# Sublime Text 3: Disable selection drag & drop from gutter

Tags: select, drag-and-drop, sublimetext

If I click and drag on gutter (line number margin) to select some lines and then release mouse and click again, ST assumes I want to move selection.
But, I don't ever want to drag & drop selection from gutter, unless I explicitly click and drag on selection. And it interferes common logic from other editors, that click and drag on gutter margin just selects lines or modifies selection, nothing more.

Is there a setting to disable this behavior, without disabling whole selection drag & drop feature?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what behavior you're talking about. I've tested this in all three platforms (Win8.1, OS X 10.8.5, Ubuntu 14.04) using ST3 build 3062, and can't get it to do what you describe. I click and drag with the left mouse button in the gutter to select several lines. I then release the left mouse button, move to an unselected line, then click on that line number with the left mouse button, and all that happens for me is the first selection disappears and the line I clicked on becomes selected. Have you modified your `.sublime-mousemap` file at all?

Comment: You were close. Click and drag in the gutter to select several lines, release mouse button, then click and drag in the gutter within the current selected lines. Selecting outside of current selection works fine, its when selecting inside the current selection from the gutter that there's a problem. Thanks.

Comment: Very disappointed this was asked a year ago because this is the only functionality I miss from np++ and most likely cannot be changed. Another way this fails is if you are ctrl-clicking multiple lines that you plan on modifying/deleting, and decide you want to select another line that is directly below one already selected, selecting it will unselect everything. 100% agree gutter should work as you describe.

Comment: @freb that adjacent line issue is the worst!  i just found out about soft undo ( ctrl + u ), which is a nice way to come back from that.

Comment: @Enteleform, the plot thickens. I primarily use Linux and just noticed that the gutter behavior is working as desired (build 1303). However, on my Windows vm it is working like you describe (same build, 1303). The main difference in how it works on Linux compared to np++ is that the selection is additive in that it doesn't redo the select, it just adds to it. I guess the question is why it doesn't it work the same on Windows. Also, nice call on "soft undo". Could have saved me some time when making a mistake after selecting 20 lines :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to preferences -> settings and add this to user settings:

```
"drag_text": false
```

I can't believe anyone would ever want text to move when trying to reselect.

Comment: ikr, I don't see the use for drag text it interferes with the selection. It's what cut/paste is used for.